# Convert a string to a set without splitting the characters

Tags: python-3.x

I have a quick question: `a='Tom'`, a type of `str`. I want to make it into a set with one item.  If I use the command `b = set(a)`, I got a set with 3 items in it, which is `set(['m',''T','o'])`. I want `set(['Tom'])`. How could I get it?   Thanks.

Comment: More problem setting:  Here "a" is derived from collections.Counter of a list. It is the key with the maximum count. I could not know beforehand what it is so I cannot do it manually. In this case, what is the way to get it into set?

Comment: Here are my codes and my fix. But it is so weird to me!!!   I used the following code and it works!!! ---- b = set([a])----. I could use b to set operations and as key to extract mapping items!!! Here are the codes:                                                   import collections
tt = ['Tom','Tom','Sam','Jon']
x = collections.Counter(tt)
print(x) 
v, k = max((v, k) for k, v in x.items())
print(' k = ',k)
print(' v = ',v)

a = k
print('a= ',a)

b = set(a)
print('b= ', b)
###  Not good
bb=set([a])
print('bb = ',bb)
### bb is good.

Answer (score 1):

The `set` builtin makes sets out of iterables. Iterating over a string yields each character one-by-one, so wrap the string in some other iterable:

```
set(['Tom'])
set(('Tom',))
```

If you're used to the mathematical notation for sets, you can just use curly braces (don't get it confused with the notation for dictionaries):

```
{'Tom'}
{'Tom', 'Bob'}
```

The resulting sets are equivalent

```
>>> {'Tom'} == set(['Tom']) == set(('Tom',))
True
```

Comment: My question is "a" is derived from collections.Counter of a list. It is the key with the maximum count. I could not know beforehand what it is so I cannot do it manually. In this case, what is the way to get it into set?

Comment: @user3092695: Exactly the same way as you would do it if `a` was replaced with `'Tom'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
set(['Tom'])
```

You just answered your own question (give list, instead of string).

Comment: How would I do it if "a" is a variable derived from collections.Counter? It is actually the key with the maximum count.  I could not assign it manually in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
a = "Tom"

b = set([a])
```

Comment: This is `tuple`, not `set`.